# CSS broken on almost every page load

Tags: support, status-norepro, design

Starting about twenty minutes ago, just after restarting my browser, SO review queues started displaying without any styling on almost every page load. Fortunately, I have an extension to reload just CSS, which does work. Unfortunately, it doesn't make it stick for the next page load, and neither does cache-bypass refreshing. No new addons or scripts installed.

Another characteristic is that the queue instructions uncollapse on the second post displayed after a load.

When looking at the console, a couple errors showed up, but the source of [the "CSS"](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=f74d6be61bfb) it was loading was an HTML "not found" response page, albeit apparently without the 404.

Seems like this extends to most pages on SO, most of the time; at least tagged question lists and question pages.

Comment: What does your browser console say? Any errors? Also, where are you located?

Comment: @NickCraver: For a bit it looked like it had cleared up, but no. I checked network results in Firefox, but didn't see any load errors. I'm using satellite in southern US. Adding errors from console to question.

Comment: It's likely a problem within your provider's network, if your satellite provider is anything like mine. The real server appears to respond appropriately with a 404 error code and a generic IIS error page.

Comment: Nathan is this still happening? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @Jin: Only occasionally; it's been a few days since the last such incident, unfortunately. Heisenbugs are not fun….

Comment: @NathanTuggy looks like a network/isp issue? Since none of us could reproduce it I'll go ahead mark it as status non-pro. But if this problem happens again consistently later please let me know.

Comment: @Jin: Will do; thanks for looking into this.